# Unwrap with Margins - Space out Islands

Tags: uv, documentation

I'm unwrapping a deformed cube, so I've set all edges to be seams. When I unwrap, I get 6 polygons as expected, but I'd like there to be a gap between them on the UV map. Currently, they are all touching each other.

The blender manual mentions a margin setting, but I cannot for the life of me find it, even after googling it, and the manual glossed over it.

Using 2.71

Answer (score 13):

Once you've unwrapped your model, you can adjust the margin at the bottom of the *Tool Shelf* (<kbd>T</kbd>):

[image]

Comment: Ah, I have to hit the + tab at the bottom. So strange. Why isn't it with the other tool shelf options...

Comment: The operator properties is a section at the bottom of the toolbar that can be hidden leaving the + to get it back. The same options are available in a floating dialog by pressing F6

Comment: @sambler - I'm on a mac, and the F3 to F7 keys do nothing. F8 does something, I get an hourglass icon, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Tick the answer checkbox, dude.