# why are the edges of uv unwrap blurred? and how to fix

Tags: uv, texture-baking

[image]

i used smart uv project and then baked and this is what happened

Answer (score 3):

The blurred part in your image is create around the **outside** of boundary of each UV island when you bake. It is called the **margin**, and is used to hide/minimise various texture sampling errors that can occur around seams in some renderers.

You can control the size using the margin setting in the bake settings panel under output (in your screenshot it is set to 16px).

You may need to reduce this value if your image is low res or your islands are very close together to avoid overlap.

You can also control how much space there is between your islands when you make your UV layout, see https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/uv_image/uv/editing/unwrapping/mapping_types.html

Comment: That worked for the bluriness however its left me with black spots all around my uv Map. Not just on the edges now

Comment: The margin is intentional, and you generally don't wan't to remove it entirely, or you can get aliasing issues around the seams in your bake. It is likely that there are problems in your unwrap, you may want to play with padding/margin values there, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35137/unwrap-with-margins-space-out-islands for example.

Answer (score 0):

When you created the uv unwrap, there´s an option: "padding", set to zero. Re-do paint job. Or scale Uvs.

Comment: Where is these options located? I can't seem to find them